# Should we implement the mhchem package to be able to typeset chemical formulas?

Tags: feature-request

When Im active on chemistry.SE, I use this feature, which allows you to typeset chemical formulas into the latex framework, a lot. And I can imagine quite a few circumstances where it could be handy e.g. in [this answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26/how-does-nuclear-fuel-reprocessing-work/112#112). Chemical-Engineering is, of course, the field which will benefit most of this.

You can see an example of mhchem in action [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22404/what-substance-in-a-gummy-bear-reacts-with-heated-potassium-chlorate-to-create-a/22405#22405), where I explained why a gummy bear burns away if in contact with heated potassium chlorate.

Comment: Good idea. Can't see how it would get in the way or cause any harm, and it could certainly be very useful for certain subjects.

Comment: I've generally used the \text{} function in the past (which seems to superficially cover some aspects), but mhchem would be awesome to have.

Comment: WHAT?!  I have another markdown subset to learn?!  </jk> On a more serious note, yes, this would be helpful to have as we pick up more questions & answers involving chemical engineering.

Comment: This may also occasionally benefit materials engineers, especially those working with polymers or ceramics.